# Geolocation autopost coordinates to php

Tags: php, geolocation

i have a problem with my code. I get coordinates to inputbox from javascript and i autopost the inputs. But in my post page no variables came.

To Get Coordinates :

```
function showlocation() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
}

function callback(position) {
  document.getElementById('latitude').value = position.coords.latitude;
  document.getElementById('longitude').value = position.coords.longitude;
}

window.onload = function () {
  showlocation();
}
```

To Autopost form to php page :

```
function gonder()
{
document.forms["geo"].submit();
}
 window.onload = gonder;


<form action="geolocation.php" method="post" name="geo" id="geo">
<input type="text" name="latitude" id="latitude">
  <input type="text" name="longitude" id="longitude">
</form>
```

But in the php page there is no variable to see.

Comment: Does it work if you remove `window.onload = gonder` and call `gonder()` inside `callback`?

Comment: can you show us your geolocation.php page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onload = function () {
  showlocation();
};

window.onload = gonder;
```

Here, `window.onload = gonder` overwrites `window.onload = function () { ... }`, so only `gonder` will run. You could fix this problem by instead calling both functions inside a single `window.onload` function:

```
window.onload = function () {
  showlocation();
  gonder();
};
```

However this will still not work, since `gonder` will execute before the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` call completes, so the form will submit while still empty. To fix this, move the call to `gonder` inside the `callback`:

```
function callback(position) {
  document.getElementById('latitude').value = position.coords.latitude;
  document.getElementById('longitude').value = position.coords.longitude;
  gonder();
}
```

Comment: when i move the gonder function inside to callback it worked. Really thank you so much for your help.